# Alternative to ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'd like to store a few variables which will be referenced throughout lifecycle, starting with a db access in PreInit event. ViewState isn't an option, since it won't persist if saved so early during the page lifecycle. Given that data should not be altered by a user, what would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Session to store your data.  I am not sure on the number of users of your system, but assuming the data you want to store is small this won't be a problem.'

Also, unless you are using a SessionPageStatePersister (or another server side persister) or encrypting your ViewState it is still possible for the user to change the ViewState.  It may be harder, but it is still possible.  By default ViewState uses HiddenFieldPageStatePersister and it stores the ViewState in a hidden field on each page (as an encoded string).  Just something worth considering.

Comment: Session would be my last resort, although it looks like I have no choice. ViewState is encrypted by default, so it is alterable, however not coherently without the machine key. I'm accepting your answer since it was the first one, although everyone said session.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope: [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) or [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx)

**Session**
If you want the data stored per user

**Application**
If you want the data stored available for all users

Answer (score 0):

You could store data in hidden fields, and if you want to obscure it, you could use some kind of encription. Of course these values would also only load in a later stage of the page lifecycle. The session object would be the obvious choice, although it's not everybody's favourite method.

Answer (score 0):

Session probably wouldn't be available at PreInit, but you could store them in variables until a later page lifecycle task, and then store them in session at that time.  I could be wrong about the session feature.  Additionally, cache is an option but caching is not user-specific; you can make it user specific by appending their user ID or session ID.

Answer (score 0):

Session is probably your best bet.  We have to use the session to store some user information, but hit a bug due to accessing it too early.  The bug is `[HttpException]: Session state has created a session id, but cannot save it because the response was already flushed by the application."`  But it will often manifest as PageRequestMangerParserErrorException.  Super fun hunting that down.  One hackish fix is to write into your Global.asax code behind:

```
public Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sessionId = Session.SessionID;
}
```

Accessing the SessionID forces the ASP.NET engine to go build the session before it normally would, making it possible to use it early.

Outside of session (or application) you have two other options: client storage and persistent storage.  The latter is a fancy way of saying "stuff it in the database", though similar alternatives exist, of course.

Client Storage is like viewstate, but more controlled.  You can use hidden fields or cookies. In fact, a cookie might work out well for you, but you'll need to encrypt the information in it if you want the user to leave it alone.  Regardless, anything you send to the client you must assume is compromised, so always do a validity check.